# typedef in class. In another class error: type has not been declared

Tags: c++, oop, typedef

In Hire.h i declared two typedefs. In Customer.h i would be able to use this typedefs. How to fix it?

```
#pragma once
#include "typedefs.h"
#include "Vehicle.h"
#include "Customer.h"
namespace rent {

typedef std::shared_ptr<Hire> shared_Hire_t;
typedef std::map<uuid_t, shared_Hire_t> mapHirePtr_t;

    class Hire
    {

    public:
    Hire(date_t start_date, Vehicle *vehicle, Customer *customer);
    virtual ~Hire();                                    

    private:
    uuid_t uuid;
    date_t start_date;
    date_t end_date;
    uint_t hire_days;
    double day_price;
    double cost;
    Vehicle *vehicle;   
    Customer *customer;

    };
    }
```

**-**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include "typedefs.h"   //uint_t, uuid_t
#include "CustomerType.h"

namespace rent {

class Hire;

class Customer
{
public:
enum EnumCustomerType {standard, medium, premium};  //to set a CustomerType
Customer(std::string name, std::string surname, std::string pesel, double balance = 0.0, EnumCustomerType enum_customer_type = standard);
virtual ~Customer();

void add_hire(shared_Hire_t hire);
void end_hire(shared_Hire_t hire);

protected:

std::string name;
std::string surname;
std::string pesel;
double balance;
EnumCustomerType enum_customer_type;
double discount;

mapHirePtr_t current_hires;
uint_t hires_count;

private:

std::unique_ptr<CustomerType> customer_type;

};
}
```

**-**

> Customer.h:31:17: error: 'shared_Hire_t' has not been declared    void
>   add_hire(shared_Hire_t hire);
>                    ^ Customer.h:32:31: error: 'shared_Hire_t' has not been declared
>                    void end_hire(shared_Hire_t hire);
>                                  ^ Customer.h:42:3: error: 'mapHirePtr_t' does not name a type    mapHirePtr_t current_hires;
>   ^ Customer.cpp:87:14: error: prototype for 'void
>   rent::Customer::add_hire(rent::shared_Hire_t)' does not match any in
>   class 'rent::Customer'
>            void Customer::add_hire(shared_Hire_t hire)
>                 ^ In file included from Customer.cpp:1:0: Customer.h:31:8: error: candidate is: void
>   rent::Customer::add_hire(int)    void add_hire(shared_Hire_t hire);
>           ^ Customer.cpp:94:14: error: prototype for 'void rent::Customer::end_hire(rent::shared_Hire_t)' does not match any in
>   class 'rent::Customer'
>            void Customer::end_hire(shared_Hire_t hire)
>                 ^ Customer.cpp:1:0: Customer.h:32:22: error: candidate is: void rent::Customer::end_hire(int)
>                    void end_hire(shared_Hire_t hire);

PS. How to separate two blocks of code in an appropriate way in stackoverflow?

Comment: I'm pretty sure not all of that code is relevant to reproduce the error. Provide a [MCVE] please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include Hire.h in Customer.h for the typedefs to be visible.
As that would introduce a circular reference i would suggest putting the typedefs in a seperate file.

Comment: So you suggest to make for example HireTypedef.h to story only typedef related with class Hire? It is only sensible solution?

Comment: You can also add the typedefs to Customer.h or include Hire.h in Customer.h in which case you would need to remove the include for Customer.h from Hire.h which would be possible since you are only using Customer* which you can replace with class Customer*  or just adding a forward declaration at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `#include "Hire.h` in Customer.h to make the definitions available there.

Unfortunately, that creates a circular dependency between the headers.

Fortunately, Hire.h doesn't need the definitions of `Customer` and `Vehicle`, so you can stop including them and just forward-declare the classes.

Hire.h:

```
#include "typedefs.h"
namespace rent {

class Vehicle;
class Customer;
class Hire;

typedef std::shared_ptr<Hire> shared_Hire_t;
typedef std::map<uuid_t, shared_Hire_t> mapHirePtr_t;

class Hire
{


// ...
```

Customer.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include "typedefs.h"   //uint_t, uuid_t
#include "CustomerType.h"
#include "Hire.h"

namespace rent {

class Customer
{
// ...
```